# Group_Concat with multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have two main tables that comprise bookings for events.
A Registrants table (Bookings) R and an Events table E.

There are also two connected tables, Field_Values V and Event_Categories C

This diagram shows the relationship
[image: Table Mapping Diagram (truncated)]

What I am trying to do is create an Invoice query that mirrors the user's shopping cart. Often a user will book multiple events in one transaction, so my invoice should have columns for the common items e.g. User Name, User Email, Booking Date, Transaction ID and aggregated columns for the invoice line item values e.g. Quantity "1,2" Description "Desc1, Desc2"  Price "10.00, 20.00"  where there are two line items in the shopping cart.

The Transaction ID (dcea4_eb_registrant.transaction_id) is unique per Invoice and repeated per line item in that sale.

I have the following query which produces rows for each line item

```
SELECT
  R.id as ID,
  E.event_date as ServiceDate,
  E.event_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY as DueDate,
  Concat('Ad-Hoc Booking:',E.title) as ItemProductService,
  Concat(R.first_name, ' ',R.last_name) as Customer,
  R.first_name as FirstName,
  R.last_name as LastName,
  R.email,
  R.register_date as InvoiceDate,
  R.amount as ItemAmount,
  R.comment,
  R.number_registrants as ItemQuantity,
  R.transaction_id as InvoiceNo,
  R.published as Status,
  
  
  E.event_date AS SERVICEDATE,
  Concat('Ad-Hoc Booking:',E.title) AS DESCRIPTION,
  R.number_registrants AS QUANTITY,
  FORMAT(R.amount / R.number_registrants,2) AS RATE,
  R.amount AS AMOUNT,
  C.category_id as CLASS,
  Concat(Group_Concat(V.field_value SEPARATOR ', '),'. ',R.comment) as Memo

FROM dcea4_eb_events E
LEFT JOIN dcea4_eb_registrants R  ON R.event_id = E.id
LEFT JOIN dcea4_eb_field_values V ON V.registrant_id = R.id
LEFT JOIN dcea4_eb_event_categories C ON C.event_id = R.event_id

WHERE 1=1
  AND V.field_id IN(14,26,27,15)
  AND R.published <> 2 /*Including this line omits Cancelled Invoices */
  AND R.published IS NOT NULL
  AND (R.published = 1 OR R.payment_method = "os_offline") 
  AND (R.register_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)

GROUP BY E.event_date, E.title, R.id, R.first_name, R.last_name, R.email,R.register_date, R.amount, R.comment

ORDER BY R.register_date DESC, R.transaction_id
```

This produces output like this
[image: Query Output sample]

I'm using the following query to try to group together the rows with a common transaction_ID (rows two and three in the last picture) - I add group_concat on the columns I want to aggregate and change the Group By to be the transaction_id

```
SELECT
  R.id as ID,
  E.event_date as ServiceDate,
  E.event_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY as DueDate,
  Concat('Ad-Hoc Booking:',E.title) as ItemProductService,
  Concat(R.first_name, ' ',R.last_name) as Customer,
  R.first_name as FirstName,
  R.last_name as LastName,
  R.email,
  R.register_date as InvoiceDate,
  R.amount as ItemAmount,
  R.comment,
  R.number_registrants as ItemQuantity,
  R.transaction_id as InvoiceNo,
  R.published as Status,
  
  
  Group_ConCat( E.event_date) AS SERVICEDATE,
Group_ConCat( Concat('Ad-Hoc Booking:',E.title)) AS DESCRIPTION,
Group_ConCat( R.number_registrants) AS QUANTITY,
Group_ConCat( FORMAT(R.amount / R.number_registrants,2)) AS RATE2,
Group_ConCat( R.amount) AS AMOUNT,
Group_ConCat( C.category_id) as CLASS,

  Concat(Group_Concat(V.field_value SEPARATOR ', '),'. ',R.comment) as Memo

FROM dcea4_eb_events E
LEFT JOIN dcea4_eb_registrants R  ON R.event_id = E.id
LEFT JOIN dcea4_eb_field_values V ON V.registrant_id = R.id
LEFT JOIN dcea4_eb_event_categories C ON C.event_id = R.event_id

WHERE 1=1
  AND V.field_id IN(14,26,27,15)
  AND R.published <> 2 /*Including this line omits Cancelled Invoices */
  AND R.published IS NOT NULL
  AND (R.published = 1 OR R.payment_method = "os_offline") 
  AND (R.register_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)

GROUP BY R.transaction_id

ORDER BY R.register_date DESC, R.transaction_id
```

But this produces this output

[image: Group Out Attempt]

It seems to be multiplying the rows. The Quantity column in the first row should just be 1 and in the second row it should be 2,1 .

I've tried using Group_Concat with DISTINCT but this doesn't work because often the values being concatenated are the same (e.g. the price for two events being booked are both the same) and  the query only returns one value e.g. 10 and not 10, 10. The latter being what I need.

I'm guessing the issue is around the way the tables are joined but I'm struggling to work out how to get what I need.

Pointers in the right direction most appreciated.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: And V and R are both INNER JOINs

Comment: @Stawberry - thanks for your steer regards the type of join needed. I take your point about data presentation in the application layer - but on this occasion I do need to get this query working. I have seen posts with similar problems and the solutions point towards aggregation before making the joins but the answers don't provide sufficient explanation for my meagre SQL ability to be able to interpret. So any further guidance would be gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

You seem determined to go in what seems to me to be the wrong direction, so here's a gentle nudge down that hill...

Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE users
(user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,username VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(101,'John'),(102,'Paul'),(103,'George'),(104,'Ringo');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales;

CREATE TABLE sales
(sale_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,purchaser_id INT NOT NULL
,item_code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,quantity INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO sales VALUES
( 1,101,'A',1),
( 2,103,'A',2),
( 3,103,'A',3),
( 4,104,'A',1),
( 5,104,'A',2),
( 6,104,'A',3),
( 7,103,'B',2),
( 8,103,'B',2),
( 9,104,'B',3),
(10,103,'B',2),
(11,104,'B',2),
(12,104,'B',1);

SELECT u.* 
     , x.sale_ids
     , x.item_codes
     , x.quantities
  FROM users u 
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT purchaser_id
            , GROUP_CONCAT(sale_id ORDER BY sale_id) sale_ids
            , GROUP_CONCAT(item_code ORDER BY sale_id) item_codes
            , GROUP_CONCAT(quantity ORDER BY sale_id) quantities
         FROM sales
        GROUP 
           BY purchaser_id
     ) x
    ON x.purchaser_id = u.user_id;
    
    +---------+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
    | user_id | username | sale_ids      | item_codes  | quantities  |
    +---------+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
    |     101 | John     | 1             | A           | 1           |
    |     102 | Paul     | NULL          | NULL        | NULL        |
    |     103 | George   | 2,3,7,8,10    | A,A,B,B,B   | 2,3,2,2,2   |
    |     104 | Ringo    | 4,5,6,9,11,12 | A,A,A,B,B,B | 1,2,3,3,2,1 |
    +---------+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you I'll give this approach a go.